# Best way for responsive design in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Which of these is the best for responsive design
create layouts like this:

**res/layout-small**

**res/layout-normal**

**res/layout-large**

**res/layout-xlarge**

or create only one layout and set its width and height to percent

I don’t know whether this is a stupid question or not, I’m just wondering what many ladies do in such situations.Thanks

Comment: Hi @Muhammed, if my answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using ConstraintLayout properly can make your app responsive almost to all screen sizes.

learn about ConstraintsLayout [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout).
read more about responsive design [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes).

Although you will still need to provide different design for landscape mode and you might need a different design for tablets.

if you need more clarifications, let me know in the comments!

Comment: hi yes I use ConstraintLayout and I always set the width and height to a percentage and in many devices the design does not change but sometimes the design changes because of this I ask the others I need to create these layouts
res/layout-small

res/layout-normal

res/layout-large

res/layout-xlarge
and set the width and height to a percentage or set the width and height to dp?

Comment: as I said you might need to have another design for tablets and bigger screen sizes. I would use the percentage whenever possible though sometimes you will have to use dp

Comment: you are welcome bro, if this was useful consider giving the answer vote up by clicking on the up arrow